# How to Change Password In PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a change password page in php, i am having problem. Kindly guide me where i am getting problem.

```
<form action="do_change_password.php" method="post">
<table width="70%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<h2>CHANGE PASSWORD</h2>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="40%" height="30">Current Password
</td>
<td width="60%">
<input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="30"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30">New Password</td>
<td>
<input name="newpassword" type="password" id="newpassword" size="30"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30">Confirm New Password</td>
<td>
<input name="confirmnewpassword" type="password" id="confirmnewpassword" size="30"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30" colspan="2" align="center">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_btn"/>
<input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset"/>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

do_change_password.php

```
<?php
include 'includes/dbConnect.php';   

$password = $_POST['password'];
$newpassword = $_POST['newpassword'];
$confirmnewpassword = $_POST['confirmnewpassword'];

$error_msg = "Field(s) cannot be empty"; 


if ($password == '' || $newpassword == ''  ||$confirmnewpassword == '')
    {
        echo $error_msg;
        exit;
    }

$result = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE password='$password'");

        if
        ($password != mysql_result($result< 0))
        {
            echo "Entered an incorrect password";
        }

        if($newpassword == $confirmnewpassword)
        {
  $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE registration SET password = '$newpassword' WHERE   password='$current_password'");      
        }

        if(!$sql)
        {
            echo "Congratulations, password successfully changed!";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "New password and confirm password must be the same!";
        }
 ?>
```

dbConnect.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
global $link;

$servername='localhost';
$dbname='school';
$dbusername='root';
$dbpassword='';
$table_Name="students";

$link = mysql_connect($servername,$dbusername,$dbpassword);

if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
else 
{
 mysql_select_db($dbname,$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
}

?>
```

I am getting this error, i am not able to change the password:
 Entered an incorrect passwordCongratulations, password successfully changed! cannot change the password
Kindly tell me where i am doing mistake.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: if i enterd value also I am getting error filed(s) cannot be empty

Comment: too much code. think about narrowing down your code samples next time

Comment: the amount of code is just fine, a couple of us have found the answer... ;)

Comment: Kindly edit the code for me plz

Comment: You are trying to get posted input values with their id's. Try to get them with their name attribues.

Comment: If this is on the public internet, you're in serious trouble. This is **dangerously insecure**. You're creating [SQL injection holes](http://bobby-tables.com/), using the hazardously out of date `mysql_query` interface, and aren't observing [best-practices for password hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing). If you need an authentication layer, you should be using a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) which comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan stop commenting and look at your answers, your question is answered... vote up the ones you like, and choose the best one by clicking the big checkmark ;)

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan don't change your question otherwise the answers will not make sense! post a new one if you have further questions!

Comment: ADVICE: table layout is outdated, use div's to structure layout

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mixed up `id` with `name` in the input tags.

Replace...

```
<input name="current" type="password" id="password" size="30"/>
```

...with...

```
<input id="current" type="password" name="password" size="30"/>
```

Basically whatever you specify as `name` in your input tags is what you'll be able to get through `$_POST`.

So `<input name="whatever" />` will be `$_POST['whatever']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name="current" type="password" id="password" size="30" name="password"/>

$password = $_POST['password'];
```

$_POST it should be accept name attribute from html tag.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your form with this .... your mistake to change your field names, and try to improve your php code see this [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

```
<form action="do_change_password.php" method="post">
<table width="70%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<h2>CHANGE PASSWORD</h2>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="40%" height="30">Current Password
</td>
<td width="60%">
<input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="30"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30">New Password</td>
<td>
<input name="newpassword" type="password" id="newpassword" size="30"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30">Confirm New Password</td>
<td>
<input name="confirmnewpassword" type="password" id="confirmnewpassword" size="30"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30" colspan="2" align="center">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_btn"/>
<input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset"/>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: $post have been fixed, now i am getting this Entered an incorrect passwordCongratulations, password successfully changed! cannot change the password

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan your issue solved or still you are waiting for solution.

Comment: Bro now i am getting the error, not been able to change password, getting this error  Entered an incorrect passwordCongratulations, password successfully changed!

Comment: Empty field prob have been resolved, thanks for that

Comment: dude, don't change your original question, otherwise the answers will make no sense... change it back how it was, accept an answer, then ask a new one!

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="do_change_password.php" method="post">
<table width="70%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" border="0">
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<h2>CHANGE PASSWORD</h2>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="40%" height="30">Current Password
</td>
<td width="60%">
<input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="30"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30">New Password</td>
<td>
<input name="newpassword" type="password" id="newpassword" size="30"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30">Confirm New Password</td>
<td>
<input name="confirmnewpassword" type="password" id="confirmnewpassword" size="30"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td height="30" colspan="2" align="center">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_btn"/>
<input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset" id="reset"/>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

try this..it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You must capture:

```
$password = $_POST['current'];
$newpassword = $_POST['new'];
$confirmnewpassword = $_POST['confirm-new'];
```

Or replace the `name` of your inputs.